Special relativity in PPN formalism
It is known that in the parameterized post-Newtonian formalism, the effective force (centripetal) can be expressed as
$$F=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}$$
multiplied by a factor of
$$1+(2+2\gamma-\beta)(v/c)^2,$$
where $\gamma=\beta=0$ and $c=\infty$ for Newtonian mechanics (thus the factor reduces to $1$), while $\gamma=\beta=1$ and $c$ is finite for General relativity (whose factor is $1+3(v/c)^2$).
Then, may I understand that the factor for special relativity is $1+2(v/c)^2$ ($γ=β=0$ and $c$ is finite), causing a lesser (~$33 \%$ less) apsidal precession than that of General relativity?
